# Randomly Generate/Pick Words

Tags: android

First off let me say I'm a beginner at programming. So far I've done only one android app that did little more than go out to the net, grab some data and do some simple calculations on it. I quite enjoyed that and would like to continue to try to learn by coding.

I have another idea I would like to turn into an app:

I have 2 lists of words. One with about 50,000 words and the other with nearly 100,000 words. What I want to do is randomly pick one word from each of those lists and keep picking until the first character of both words is the same. 
But right off the bat I find myself stuck because I don't know the proper way of storing those lists for my purpose(plain txt? csv? xml? something else?).

Could someone please point me in the right direction? It seems like I'm getting nowhere by googling alone.

Comment: plain txt, csv, and xml are all valid options. Personally I might go with xml and use the built in arrays.xml file to store your words. However if it were me it would also mostly come down to what format the lists are presently in, I'd pick whatever is closest to their current format so that I wouldn't have to try to reformat the lists.

Comment: I like Tim's idea about arrays.xml, it will work fine especially if you'll want to localize your app. But I'd go with a plaint .txt since it's the most memory-saving.

Comment: The lists are in an excel spreadsheet. I can export the lists to other formats pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this many words in both data set, it could be quite long to pick at random until the first letter matches.

Here's an idea to make this faster. Store both data in a [SQLite table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). Then you can select a random first letter and query a random row from each table which begins with your letter. For example, the following query returns one random row with a column's value beginning by A

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE wordlike 'A%' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I have considered a database but since the data is not relational I thought it might be overkill. But if you say it will perform better it's worth a try. Think I'll try plain txt and SQLite and see which works better. Thanks.

Comment: Even though it's not relational, the lookup time should be faster with a database. Now you can still apply my trick with plain text file too, by first picking the first letter then randomly pick a word starting with the letter (easier if the file is ordered alphabetically)

Comment: I actually did sort it alphabetically in the spreadsheet. Do queries work on plain txts as well? The way I wanted to try(with txt) is get the number of lines in both lists as a sort of range for a randomly picked number and then retrieve the word at that position(index?).